# Error "! Missing delimiter (. inserted)." in the same line, even if I change the document order

Tags: errors, compiling, delimiters

The error in the line 196 in the next code, always appear, even if I change the order of my document structure. This doesn't let me compile peacefully,

¿Where is the error?

This is my code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}
\title[Teoría de Grupos]{Teoría de Grupos}  
\author[Juan Pablo M. Diaz ]{Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\
\vspace{1cm}Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\ Sede Manizales}
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 
%%%


%%%%
\frame{\frametitle{Definiciones y ejemplos}
\begin{block}{Operación Binario}
Dado un conjunto $S$, una operación binaria en $S$ se denota como $''+''$ o $''\cdot''$.\\
Satisface que si $a,b \in S$ entonces $a+b\in S$ o $a \cdot b \in S$, respectivamente.
\end{block}
\begin{exampleblock}{Ejemplos}
\begin{itemize}
\item Dados dos reales $a=3$ y $b=6 \in \mathbb{R}$

$3+6 = 9 \ in \mathbb{R}$ La suma en reales es una operación binaria.

$a+b =c \in \mathbb{R}$
\item En el conjunto de matrices de orden $3 \times 2 = M_{3\times2}$. Si $A,B \in M_{3\times 2}$

$A_{3\times 2}+B_{3\times 2}=C_{3\times 2}\Rightarrow +_{3\times 2} $ es binaria
\item Matrices Cuadradas, $\det \neq 0$)\\
Defino $(\cdot)$, como la multiplicación usual entre matrices.¿Es binaria?
Dados $A,B \in D_{2 \times 2}$, $\det A \neq 0$ y $\det B \neq 0$.

$\det (A\cdot B) = \det A \det B \neq 0 \Rightarrow A\cdot B \in D_{2\times 2} $


\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}
}

%%%%
\frame{
Tenemos entonces $(\mathbb{R}, \cdot),(M_{3\times2}, +), (D_{2\times 2}, \cdot)$ son ejemplos de estructuras algebraicas
\begin{block}{Algébra y Grupos}
\begin{itemize}
\item Algebra: Rama de las Matemáticas que se encarga de estudiar las estructuras algebraicas
\item Grupos: Hacen parte de un conjunto caracteristico de las estructuras algebraicas
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=4cm, width=8cm]{AStruct}
  \caption{Estructura del algebra}
\end{figure}
}

\frame{
\begin{block}{Semigrupo}
Es la estructura algebraica mas simple.
\begin{itemize}
\item $S$ conjunto
\item Operación Binaria ($\cdot$), asociativa $(ab)c=a(bc)$
\item Se nota como$(S,\cdot)$ o $(S,+)$
\end{itemize}
\textit{Ejemplo:} $M_{3\times 2}$
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Grupo}
\begin{itemize}
\item $(G,\cdot)$
\item $a(bc)=(ab)c$
\item Existe $e \in G | ea = a \forall a\in G$
\item Para cada $a\in G \text{existe}\left{ a' | aa'=e \right }$
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
}

\frame{ \frametitle{Ejemplos de grupos}

\begin{block}{Enteros Modulo $n$ bajo la adición}
\begin{itemize}
\item Se nota como $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{n})$ bajo la adición
\item Sean $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ Y $n$ un entero positivo. Definimos la relación $x \equiv y \mod n \text{si} x-y=qn$
Esto es una relación de equivalencia. Se denota $\overline{x}$ la clase de equivalencia que contiene al elemento x.
Los elementos de nuestro grupo van a ser las clases de equivalencia generadas por la relación de equivalencia. Definamos nuestra operación binaria como $\overline{x}+\overline{y} =  \overline{x+y}$.
Veamos que esta operación está bien definida. si $\overline{x}=\overline{x'}$ y $\overline{y} = \overline{y'}$ entonces $n| x-x'$ y $n|y-y'$ por tanto $n|(x-y)+(x'-y')$. De esto $\overline{x+y}=\overline{x'+y'}$. Claramente el $\overline{0}$ es el elemento identidad y $\overline{-x}$ es el inverso de $\overline{x}$.
Tenemos entonces que $(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(n)},+)$ es un grupo abeliano(Conmutativo) de orden n.
Finalmente $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(n)} = \{ \overline{0},\overline{1},\ddots,\overline{n-1}\}$
\end{itemize}
\end{block}

}

\frame{ \frametitle{Permutaciónes}
\begin{block}{Enteros Modulo n bajo la multiplicación}
$(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{(n)},+)$
\end{block}

\begin{itemize}
\item Es el grupo mas importante en que se basa la teoría de grupos aplicada a la Fisica
\item Sea $X$ un conjunto, y $G$ el conjunto de funciones \textbf{biyectivas} de $X$ a $X$(Fisica: Posiciónes Iniciales, Posiciónes Finales; Condición de Biyeccion)
\item La operación binaria es la Composición de funciones. Dados $f$ y $g \in G, \hspace{.2cm} fg\in G$
\item El elemento Unidad es la función identidad.
\item El resto de condiciónes se verifican usando resultados de composición de funciones biyectivas
\end{itemize}


}



\frame{
\begin{block}{Simetrias de una figura Geométrica; $(S,\cdot)$}
\begin{itemize}
\item X Conjunto de todos los puntos de alguna figura geometrica.
\item Una permutación $\sigma: X \rightarrow X$ es una simetría si preserva distancias.
\[
d(a,b)=d(\sigma(a),\sigma(b))
\]
\item \text{Composición de Simetrías es un Grupo.}
\begin{align*}
\textit{Dem} si \sigma, \tau \in S &\text{(Conjunto de simetrias)}\\
d(\sigma \tau(a),\sigma \tau(b)) &= d(\tau(a),\tau(b)) = d(a,b)\\
\end{align*}
Si $a \in S$ entonces $a^{-1} \in S$
\begin{align*}
\text{Dem:} d(\sigma^{-1}(a),\sigma^{-1}(b))=&d(\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(a)),\sigma(\sigma^{-1}(a)))\\
                        =&d(a,b) 
\end{align*}
\item La simetrias que preservan distancias, son un subgrupo de las Permutaciones en $x$
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%5 incluirgraficas
\frame{
\begin{align*}
0^{\circ} &\rightarrow  \begin{array}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$e$}\\
1&\rightarrow&1\\
2&\rightarrow&2\\
3&\rightarrow&3\\
\end{array}
\hspace{1cm} e = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
1&2&3
\end{array}\right) \hspace{.5cm} 
\\
\frac{2\pi}{3}=120^{\circ} &\rightarrow  \begin{array}{ccccc}
& $a$ & & $a$ &\\
1&\rightarrow&2&\rightarrow&3\\
2&\rightarrow&3&\rightarrow&1\\
3&\rightarrow&1&\rightarrow&2\\
\end{array}
\hspace{1cm} a = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
2&3&1
\end{array}\right) \hspace{1cm} a^2= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
3&1&2
\end{array}\right)
\\
\frac{4\pi}{3}=-120 &\rightarrow  \begin{array}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{$b$}\\
1&\rightarrow&3\\
2&\rightarrow&1\\
3&\rightarrow&2\\
\end{array}
\hspace{1cm}  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
3&1&2
\end{array}\right)= a^2
\end{align*}
}

\frame{\frametitle{Rotaciones}

La rotacion $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ es equivalente a realizar la rotación $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ dos veces(Esto coincide con el sentido intuitivo dede rotar)
\[
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
1&2&3
\end{array}\right),\hspace{.5cm}a^2b= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
3&2&1
\end{array}\right), \hspace{.5cm} ab = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
2&1&3
\end{array}\right)
\]

En este caso las simetrias del triangulo, quedan especifícadas por el efecto en los tres vertices$|S|=3\times 2\times1$\\
Este grupo se lla $D_3= \text{Grupo Diedral de grado 3}$
}

\frame{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[height=5cm ,width=10cm]{tabla}
\caption(Tabla de Multiplicación $D_3$)
\end{figure}•
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's `\left\{...\right\}`, not `\left{...\right}` However, the correct way to input it is `Para cada $a\in G$ existe $\{ a' \mid aa'=e \}$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error: printed braces must be input as `\{` and `\}` (or `\lbrace` and `\rbrace`). It's illegal to have

```
\left{ a' | aa'=e \right}
```

and it should be

```
\left\{ a' | aa'=e \right\}
```

On the other hand, `\left` and `\right` here do nothing (well, to be precise they just add unwanted space) and it's better avoiding them.

Some other points.

- `se denota como $''+''$ o $''\cdot''$.` should be

  ```
  se denota como ``$+$'' o ``$\cdot$''.
  ```

  with the quotes *outside* math.
- `Existe $e \in G | ea = a \forall a\in G$` should be

  ```
  Existe $e \in G \mid ea = a$, $\forall a\in G$
  ```

  so to give some space
- `Para cada $a\in G \text{existe}\left{ a' | aa'=e \right }$` should be

  ```
  Para cada $a\in G$ existe $\{ a' \mid aa'=e \}$
  ```

  so the spacing would be right.

Comment: How did you find out where was the mistake?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz I looked for `\left` at line 96 and saw the I escaped braces